# How can i use csharp code in xslt to transform xml in Online transformer

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, msxsl

My code is working on visual studio but I don't want to depend on visual studio.
When I transform the same code in an online transformer I'm getting this error.

```
XPST0017 XPath syntax error at char 0 on line 14 near {...:CurrentDateTime('yyyy-MM-d...}:
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {urn:my-scripts}CurrentDateTime()
```

[Here is the link to the online transformer with the code](http://xsltransform.net/bwe3bM/1)

If the site is not working here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                 
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
            xmlns:csharp="urn:my-scripts" 
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl csharp">

<xsl:template match="/Employees">

    <xsl:variable name="sDate" select="string(Employee/@date)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="stringDate" select="string($sDate)"/>
    
    <p><xsl:value-of select="$stringDate"/></p>
    <xsl:value-of select="csharp:CurrentDateTime('yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
</xsl:template>

<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="csharp">
<msxsl:assembly name="System.Core"/>
<msxsl:assembly name="System.Xml.Linq"/>
<msxsl:assembly name="System.Linq"/>
<msxsl:assembly name="System.Collections"/>
<msxsl:using namespace="System.Linq"/>
<msxsl:using namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
<msxsl:using namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
<msxsl:using namespace="System.Globalization"/>
<![CDATA[

   public string CurrentDateTime(string format)
   {
        // default format
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format)) {
            format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        }

        return DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
   }
 ]]>
</msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is difficult to expose a public online transformer opening up XSLT to the full .NET platform by allowing `msxsl:script` as that way any XSLT code can embed and execute any C#/.NET code so I wouldn't expect an online service to expose such a security risk. If you want/need to use XslCompiledTransform with `msxsl:script` and C# embedded then it should be possible to write your own C# application to do that and that you can then use independent of VS.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong question. XSLT (even version 1.0) is Turing-complete. You do not need to use C# extensions in order to format a date. If you do want to use them, then you must use a processor that supports them.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default engine on that site might not support the features you're using. Changing to Xalan 2.7.1 (at the top between Share and Help) got me the below output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><p>12-Jan-2022</p>
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you can probably remove the C# code and use current-datetime() - https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-2nd-edition/9780596527211/re68.html

Comment: where do you changed?

Comment: I don't want to use only current date.

Comment: Actually, I will be validating the date format. And that date string will be coming from the XML node as a string. This code is added just as a sample so is there any way we can use c# in XSLT in the online transformer

Comment: @WillMoffat Changing the processor to Xalan removes the error message - but it does not execute the unrecognized code.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> My code is working on visual studio but I don't want to depend on visual studio.

Your code as written is not dependent on visual studio, but it is dependent on Microsoft XSLT extensions. If you want your code to be portable you are going to have to get rid of these dependencies, in particular the use of `msxsl:script`.

In XSLT 2.0 you can do what you are trying to achieve using the `current-dateTime()` and `format-dateTime()` functions (though the formatting string will be a bit different). If you do this, however, you won't be able to use the Microsoft XSLT processors, which only support XSLT 1.0.